# geohashTrie for location Nodes

Tags: cypher, neo4j-spatial

I found [image: this image] from [here](https://neo4j.com/blog/driving-predictive-analytics-neo4j/) that shows the possibilty of geohashTrie in neo4j.

My question is how to do that ? the cypher code ?